# Extending recursive modules

Tags: module, ocaml

So when you define the structure of a module, it's possible to extend another module off of it:

```
module Base = struct
  type t = Name of string
end

module Child = struct
  include Base
end

Child.Name "test" 
(* - : Child.t = Child.Name "test" *)
```

However, when working with [recursive modules using recursive signatures](https://blogs.janestreet.com/a-trick-recursive-modules-from-recursive-signatures/), I run into issues when I try to extend a module:

```
module rec Base : sig
  type t = | Name of string
end = Base

and Child : sig
  include Base
end = Child
```

When I do this, I get an error saying:

```
Error: Unbound module type Base
```

Can you not extend modules when working with this recursive module trick? Am I misunderstanding something or doing something wrong?

Comment: I'd add that generally speaking, it is a good idea to stay away from recursive modules.

Comment: @ÉtienneMillon How come? Do you have any articles you could link me to regarding this or something?

Comment: This is marked as experimental and subject to breaking changes in the manual, type inference is degraded, you can't put them in separate files. I think that there have been soundness bugs in the past. Breaking the recursion or moving it between types and values is almost always the good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me your problem is that `Base` is a module, not a module type. When including in a `sig ... end` construct you need a type. When including in a `struct ... end` construct you need a module. That's why the first example works and the second one doesn't.

If I change `Base` to `module type of Base` I get this error:

```
Error: Illegal recursive module reference
```

So I suspect this particular (somewhat strange) type of recursive definition isn't supported.

If you define the module type separately, you can make it work:

```
module type BASE = sig type t = Name of string end

module rec Base : BASE = Base

and Child : sig
    include BASE
end = Child
```

Comment: Ah this makes sense; I can't include a module's definition in a signature definition. Thanks Jeffrey

Comment: If you don't mind defining the module type separatelly you can get the structure you want (see above).

Answer (score 0):

Jeffrey Scofield already gave a good answer. I'd just like to add that `include` is just syntactic sugar. So if it is `include` which is causing you trouble, a solution might be to expand it. In the first of your examples that would lead to

```
module Base = struct
  type t = Name of string
end

module Child = struct
  type t = Name of string
end
```

Apparently, your examples are simplified versions of what you really want to do. As shown, there is no need to use `rec` at all. So I can only guess how much recursion you really need. According to Jeffrey Scofield's answer, the combination of `rec` and `include` is problematic. Possibly, getting rid of `include` suffices for you.